# How to toggle between fragments

Tags: android

I have an app that has 1 Main Activity and 5 main fragments. When the MainActivity is created I create a List containing each of the 5 fragments. The user is presented with a tab bar on the bottom of the screen which he/she can use to navigate between fragments. How do I set this up so as when the user selects a tab, the corresponding fragment is shown **without creating a new instance of it**? Just want to change the view on the screen to the already created fragment.

I am using a BottomBar from https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar which calls a "onTabSelected" interface method when a tab is pressed.

Comment: please show code of how you replace fragment

Comment: I'm working on building the feature now. Looking for thoughts on the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 5 Fragments with the library you specified like this. The layout file should look like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<!-- This could be your fragment container, or something -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/contentContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottomBar" />

<com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
    android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:bb_tabXmlResource="@xml/bottombar_tabs" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The containing Activity class will replace the Framelayout with Fragment depending on the Fragment selected from the BottomBar View. A simple example

```
public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Fragment fragment;
private FragmentManager fragmentManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_three_tabs);

    BottomBar bottomBar = (BottomBar) findViewById(R.id.bottomBar);
    bottomBar.setOnTabSelectListener(new OnTabSelectListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(@IdRes int tabId) {
            if(tabId == R.id.tab_home){
                fragment = new HomeFragment();
            }
            if(tabId == R.id.tab_favorite){
                fragment = new FavoriteFragment();
            }
        }
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.contentContainer, fragment).commit();
    });

    bottomBar.setOnTabReselectListener(new OnTabReselectListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabReSelected(@IdRes int tabId) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), TabMessage.get(tabId, true), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}

}
```

Then you can create individual Fragment with their content like below

```
public class FavoriteFragment extends Fragment {

   public FavoriteFragment() {
   }

   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_favorite, container, false 
   );
  }
}
```

Comment: Using your code, the program will create a new Fragment each time the user selects a tab. I'm looking to re-use the fragments my app creates in MainActivity's OnCreate.

Comment: Also, OnTabReselected is only called if the user selects the tab he/she is current viewing. If he/she navigates to a different tab, and then navigates back, OnTabSelected is called each time.